# Кодировка в xp_cmdshell (MS SQL 2008)

Tags: python, sql-server, кодировка, codepage

Делаю запрос:

```
exec xp_cmdshell N'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37\python.exe" G:\mb\test.py'
```

В test.py: `print('Привет')`

В SSMS получаю `╧ЁштхЄ`.

Как получить правильную кодировку?
Скрипт, запущенный из командной строки выводит верную кодировку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть средства определения кодировки по полученным кракозябрам (например [такой](https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/advanced/)). Так можно определить, что и где в какой кодировке кодировать. Делается это средствами методов [encode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#str.encode) и [decode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=encode#bytes.decode) строк. На русском тоже можно найти, что почитать (например [здесь](https://py-my.ru/post/4bfb3c6a1d41c846bc00009b/))

В частности, у вас получается, что скрипт сохранен в кодировке cp1251, а выводится в консоль в cp866. Одним из методов решения проблемы можно порекомендовать смену кодировочной страницы консоли.

```
> chcp 1251
```

Comment: Про encode я знаю, дает такой вывод b'\xcf\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2'. chcp я тоже пробовал через батник, результата нет. И это пробовал sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='cp1251')

Comment: Вы так и не прочли про работу с кодировками? Вот это: `b'\xcf\xf0\xe8\xe2\xe5\xf2'` - байтовое представление строки. У вас в консоль выводятся не байты, а текст в кодировке. Надо из начальной кодировки перевести в байты, затем передать на вывод в целевой кодировке. То есть в вашем случае: `bstr = str.encode('cp1251'); print(bstr.decode('cp866'))`

Comment: Вы правы. Так работает: print(a.encode('cp866','ignore').decode('cp1251','ignore')). Благодарю

Comment: ну тогда отметьте ответ как решение :)